# Color Restoration using Color Palette

Tags: texturing, compositing-nodes, shaders, lighting

I was recently looking at an interesting video and I came across this thing https://youtu.be/-0MD1g_5dV4?t=217 . This is a timed link which shows clicking of pictures with a color standard palette in the field. I'm assuming it is for correcting colors later on in the image.

Can someone explain a little bit in detail of how to use this color palette from the photo in correcting colors?

Can we do this using shaders and lighting within Blender?

Comment: Be more clear please. What do you want us to explain? How color correction works with using a palette?

Comment: Yes. Sorry if I wasn't clear. I want to know how color correction works using a palette

Comment: Those [Color checker](http://xritephoto.com/colorchecker-passport-photo) charts are used as reference to have known colors within the image, they can help to create profiles for the camera used, so that you can achieve accurate color rendition when converting images between different color spaces.